# How can I map an array of Firestore DocumentReferences to an array of DocumentData?

Tags: typescript, promise, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make a Google Cloud Function which reads a collection of Firestore Documents and performs an action these documents. These Documents should be read once and stored in an array to reduce the needed read operations. But I cannot make it right so that the iteration over my array starts after finishing the reading part.

```
export const matchUsers = functions
  .region("europe-west1")
  .pubsub
  .topic("matchUsers")
  .onPublish(async message => {
    console.log("Matching invoked...")

    await firebase.firestore().collection("matchData").listDocuments().then(docRefs => {
      const docs: admin.firestore.DocumentData[] = []

      docRefs.forEach(async docRef => {
        await docRef.get().then(snapshot => {
          const data = snapshot.data()
          if (data) {
            console.log("BPM: " + data.bpm)   # gets called
            docs.push(data)
          }
        })
      })

      console.log("Start loop")
      docs.forEach(doc => {
        console.log("BPM: " + doc.bpm)   # never gets called
      })
      console.log("Finish loop")

    })

  });
```

Output:

```
Matching invoked...
Start loop
Finish loop
BPM: 120
```

I would expect the output to be:
Output:

```
Matching invoked...
BPM: 120
Start loop
BPM: 120
Finish loop
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use get() instead of listDocuments()? get() would be easier, since all the document snapshots would be in memory for you to work with, instead of having to get() them each individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
export const matchUsers = functions
  .region("europe-west1")
  .pubsub
  .topic("matchUsers")
  .onPublish(async message => {
    console.log("Matching invoked...")

    await firebase.firestore().collection("matchData").get().then(docRefs => {
      const docs: admin.firestore.DocumentData[] = []

      docRefs.forEach(docRef => {
        const data = docRef.data()
        console.log("BPM: " + data.bpm)   # gets called
        docs.push(data)
      })

      console.log("Start loop")
      docs.forEach(doc => {
        console.log("BPM: " + doc.bpm)
      })
      console.log("Finish loop")
    })

  });
```

It looks you are mixing async with sync operations and it's not working the way you are expecting, also `get()` it's good enough for the case.

Lastly, watch on timeout if your collection is big.

Good luck